React vite polyfills errors on using "@xchainjs/xchain-crypto" project
in this configuration of vite. i am still got error on pollyfills
bellow i am provide the function and the error i am using and faching
React vite polyfills errors on using "@xchainjs/xchain-crypto"
const keystore = await encryptToKeyStore(seedPhrase, password);

when i am call the function named
encryptToKeyStore()
then its shows the error

Error generating keystore: TypeError: crypto_default.randomBytes is not a function
at @xchainjs_xchain-crypto.js?v=91e0a32a:47321:31
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at @xchainjs_xchain-crypto.js?v=91e0a32a:45983:67
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (@xchainjs_xchain-crypto.js?v=91e0a32a:45965:10)
at encryptToKeyStore (@xchainjs_xchain-crypto.js?v=91e0a32a:47316:47)
at generateKeystore (keystoreUtilsFunctions.ts:25:28)
at handleCreate (CreateKeyStore.tsx:21:30)

how can i solve this
